# Extract every "leaf-pack" from a pack of nested packs

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

`ExtractEveryPack<Pack>::type` is the pack of all "leaf-packs" in `Pack`.
For example, `ExtractEveryPack<  Pack<double, Pack<int, char>, int, Pack<long, short>> >::type` is `Pack< Pack<int, char>, Pack<long, short> >`.
But "outer packs" are not returned.  Only the most inner packs (which I'm calling "leaf packs") are extracted.  So

```
ExtractEveryPack<Pack<Pack<int, double>, char, Pack<long, Pack<Pack<int, char>, Pack<char, Pack<double, int>>>, char>, int, Pack<short, int>>>::type,
```

is

```
Pack< Pack<int, double>, Pack<int, char>, Pack<double, int>, Pack<short, int>.
```

My idea: `ExtractEveryPack<T>::type` is `T` by default.  Then recursively, apply `ExtractEveryPack` to every type and remove all types that are not packs:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename, typename> struct RemoveNonPacksHelper;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Accumulated>
struct RemoveNonPacksHelper<P<>, P<Accumulated...>> {
    using type = P<Accumulated...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Accumulated>
struct RemoveNonPacksHelper<P<First, Rest...>, P<Accumulated...>> : RemoveNonPacksHelper<P<Rest...>, P<Accumulated...>> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types, typename... Rest, typename... Accumulated>
struct RemoveNonPacksHelper<P<P<Types...>, Rest...>, P<Accumulated...>> : RemoveNonPacksHelper<P<Rest...>, P<Accumulated..., P<Types...>>> {};

template <typename> struct RemoveNonPacks;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct RemoveNonPacks<P<Types...>> : RemoveNonPacksHelper<P<Types...>, P<>> {};

template <typename T> struct Identity { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct ExtractEveryPack : Identity<T> {};  // Do nothing for non-packs.

// The key idea here, but apparently not correct:
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct ExtractEveryPack<P<Types...>> :
    RemoveNonPacks<P<typename ExtractEveryPack<Types>::type...>> {};

// Testing
template <typename...> struct Pack {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same< 
        RemoveNonPacks< Pack<Pack<int, double>, char, Pack<long, double, char>, int, Pack<short, int>> >::type,
        Pack<Pack<int, double>, Pack<long, double, char>, Pack<short, int>>
    >::value << std::endl;  // true

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        ExtractEveryPack<Pack<Pack<int, double>, char, Pack<long, Pack<Pack<int, char>, Pack<char, Pack<double, int>>>, char>, int, Pack<short, int>>>::type,
        Pack< Pack<int, double>, Pack<int, char>, Pack<double, int>, Pack<short, int> >
    >::value << std::endl;  // false (darn!)
}
```

What's wrong here?  My plan or the implementation of it?  What would be a better plan?

For what it's worth, here is a helper struct `IsLeafPack` to determine if a pack does not consist of other packs or not (tested), though I haven't yet figured how to use it:

```
template <typename> struct IsLeafPack;

template <template <typename...> class P>
struct IsLeafPack<P<>> : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class P2, typename... Types, typename... Rest>
struct IsLeafPack<P<P2<Types...>, Rest...>> : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct IsLeafPack<P<First, Rest...>> : IsLeafPack<P<Rest...>> {};
```

Comment: Right now your second type is actually `Pack<Pack<>, Pack<Pack<Pack<>, Pack<Pack<> > > >, Pack<> > `

Comment: Oh.  I guess `RemoveNonPacks` is accidentally removing the non-packs from the leaf-packs instead of stopping at the leaf packs.  Hmmm... How to tell it when to stop then?

Comment: Also, one outer pack can produce any number of leaf packs. `RemoveNonPacks<P<typename ExtractEveryPack<Types>::type...>>` can never produce more than `sizeof...(Types)` packs in the result, so it can't possibly be correct.

Comment: Perhaps defining a helper struct IsLeafPack to determine ahead of time if a pack does not consist of other packs would help?  I added that struct in the question now (tested to be correct), if it's of any use.  I haven't yet figured out how to use it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is correct. But the result of applying `ExtractEveryPack` can be any arbitrary number (including 0) of leaf packs. So instead of returning a single type, it must return a pack of types. These packs can then be concatenated to produce the final output.

```
// A pack template.
template <typename...> struct Pack {};

// Test if Ts... contains any pack - not necessarily a Pack.
template <typename... Ts> 
struct contains_any_pack : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... TPs, typename... Ts> 
struct contains_any_pack<P<TPs...>, Ts...> : std::true_type {};

template <class F, typename... Ts> 
struct contains_any_pack<F, Ts...> : contains_any_pack<Ts...> {};

// concatenates a list of Pack's into one Pack.
template <typename... Ts> struct concat_packs;

template <typename... Ts>
struct concat_packs<Pack<Ts...>> { using type = Pack<Ts...>; };

template <typename... Ts, typename... T1s, typename... T2s>
struct concat_packs<Pack<Ts...>, Pack<T1s...>, T2s... > 
     : concat_packs<Pack<Ts..., T1s...>, T2s... > {};


// T isn't a pack - return an empty Pack
template <typename T>
struct ExtractEveryPack { using type = Pack<>; };  

// if P<Ts...> is a leaf pack, return it wrapped in a Pack.
// else, apply ExtractEveryPack to Ts... recursively,
// and concatenate the results
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct ExtractEveryPack<P<Ts...>> { 
    using type = typename std::conditional<contains_any_pack<Ts...>::value,
                                  typename concat_packs<typename ExtractEveryPack<Ts>::type...>::type,
                                  Pack<P<Ts...>>>::type; 
};
```

To simplify implementation, the above has `ExtractEveryPack` always returning a `Pack` of leaf packs. The type of the leaf packs, however, are not restricted to `Pack`s.